# labelless, unlabeled or without label

Tags: word-usage

I am currently developing an application that includes a tree view. If some of the tree view items have no label, I give the user a feedback about this; something like "item without label found". I have found "unlabeled" and "labelless" as alternatives to "without label". However, especially "Labelless item found" sounds a bit funny to me.

Does "Unlabeled item found" or "Labelless item found" sound correct to a native speaker? Is "labelless" some kind of neologism (in such contexts)? I could find it only in the Wiktionary.

Comment: I'd go with "unlabeled item", or "item without label".  But this is more a question of opinion.

Comment: Or *no label found,* as this should be the exception.

Comment: Please don't give a feedback. It's just feedback, no a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, we tend to use **-less**, **un-** and **free** to denote a particular type or category of something, for example seedless grapes, unsweetened juice and gluten free biscuits.

**without** can be used in the same way, but it can also be used to describe an individual item that does not have a property that this type of item normally has, for example a book without a cover.

This difference may simply be that the first three are adjectival, whereas **without** is a preposition. The adjectives give a stronger impression of a type rather than an individual case.

Note that the term **no label** does not usually refer to the absence of a physical label. It is used for something that is unclassifiable or for something not associated with the major brands.

From your description, it sounds that the **without** option is most appropriate.

Note also that, when you add **-ed** to a word ending in a vowel and an l, the l is doubled, so label -> labelled.